# Is there a way to loop through properties of a list of objects using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to dynamically create a dictionary where the key will be the name of a property of an object, and the value would be the result of a linq query selecting that property.

```
MyObject[] records = getRecords(); 
foreach (property in MyObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    data[property.Name] = records.Select(r => new { x = r.Date.ToString(), y = r.propertyInfo}).ToArray(); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use more Reflection:

```
property.GetValue(r)
```

You should also use `ToDictionary()`:

```
data = typeof(MyObject).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `MyObject` is a class, not an object. `GetType()` is a non-static function of `MyObject`, therefore you can only call if after you've created a `new Myobject()` I assume you want to use `typeof(MyObject)`.

- First we create the sequence of `PropertyInfo` objects for all public readable properties of class `MyObject`.
- Then for every propertyInfo we create a sequence of value of the property of every `MyObject` in records.
- Finally we put sequence in one dictionary

Note that while creating the query in small steps, nothing is enumerated, only the query is created. Only `GetProperties` and `ToDictionary` will enumerate.

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> records = GetRecords();
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> readableProperties= typeof(MyObject).GetProperties
    .Where(property => property.CanRead);

var propertyValues = readableProperties   // for every property
    .Select(propertyInfo => new           // create one new object of anonymous type
{                                                     
    PropertyName = propertyInfo.Name,     // with the name of the property
    PropertyValues = records              // and a sequence of all values of this property
        .Select(record => propertyInfo.GetValue(record))
}
```

Finally to dictionary: key is the property name, value is the sequence of propertyValues:

```
var result = propertyValues       // put every item in the collection of propertyValues
    .ToDictionary(                // into a dictionary 
    item => item.PropertyName,    // Key is the PropertyName of each item
    item => item.PropertyValues); // Value is the sequence of PropertyValues of each item
```

Comment: Wow! This is really good! I didn't think of converting it to an intermediary dictionary of property name to property values. Thanks!!